# In which episode does Tsuna get stronger?

Tags: reborn

I would like to know in which episode Tsuna gets stronger, so that I can tell my friend and get him to stop bothering me!

Can anyone answer it for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, he enters Hyper Dying Will Mode in episode 26, and apparently after doing so by means of the pill or bullet, the person should be able to do it on their own, but Tsuna still can't as of episode 35; he doesn't seem to have gotten any stronger.

Answer (score 2):

He gets stronger in episode 25, and the story takes on a shonen-ish type of twist.

The episode is aptly named too:

> "I Want to Win! Moment of Awakening"

He can use the [Hyper Dying Will Mode](http://reborn.wikia.com/wiki/Hyper_Dying_Will_Mode) which is a calmer version of the Dying Will Mode.

Answer (score 0):

He actually gets stronger in episode 25 as he obtains his mittens and gets shot with a new bullet allowing him to use fire (his deathperation flames with his mittens)

P.S: Sorry I forgot the bullet name

Answer (score 0):

He first goes badass mode on episode 25. But he doesn't truly actually start getting *stronger* until they start training in the Varia arc, which is the entire second season.

So basically, the whole 1st season is dedicated to building up relationships so that the family bond is solid and powerful so that they can really go crazy in season 2. However, after it starts getting crazy, it never stops.